# Why is Jena-iri module javadoc absent of jena 4?

Tags: jena

as the title suggest, i am wondering why the jena-iri module is completely absent of the javadoc in jena 4. Is the package about to be deprecated ? how does it related to the package org.apache.jena.irix ?

I mean in code we still have access to jena-iri.

Can someone be kind as to clarify the difference and purpose of both jena-iri and org.apache.jena.irix ?

Comment: The jena-iri javadoc is there : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-iri/4.0.0/jena-iri-4.0.0-javadoc.jar   Who is "we" and what software are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the link. We was “I” sorry. I just meant that from resolving Jena-libs I could still see the package and use it, but could not find the doc online

Comment: Your build system should pull in the javadoc as before. There were not any intended changes to the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are details in the [pre-release news for Jena 4.0.0](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r1355e05bfca813af013819ef342906a285e790dd6c399f13c9367b89%40%3Cusers.jena.apache.org%3E), the [community announcement](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r64bc917638f6964843181a95a2d92bfe8cf013b06eddf4402080669b%40%3Cusers.jena.apache.org%3E) and the [IRIx javadoc](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/irix/package-summary.html).

The package is not going to be deprecated or removed.

IRIx is a wrapper abstraction to allow for multiple IRI implementations.

jena-iri is the active implementation in Jena 4.0.0.

This change allows for an additional IRI parser that is centred on the task of checking incoming data with lower overhead.

Comment: Javadoc link's dead.

Comment: Java >=11 does things differently to java <=8. Search is the access pattern these days:
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org.apache.jena.core/org/apache/jena/irix/package-summary.html